# Find difference between dates in consecutive rows

Tags: r

I know this has been asked before but the answers I have found seem to rely on `POSIXct` whereas I don't see why I cant do this with date

I have data like

```
Person Event VisitDate
1       RFA   2004-06-04
1       EMR   2016-06-03
1       Nil   2016-06-05
```

I want to get the difference between the dates in a separate column (eventually to average the difference of the dates over all Person ids).

Expected output:

Person Event VisitDate         Date Difference in days
    1       RFA   2004-06-04
    1       EMR   2016-06-03      4383
    1       Nil   2016-06-05        2

So far I have used:

```
EndoSubsetOnSurveil %>% 
  arrange(Person, as.Date(EndoSubsetOnSurveil$VisitDate, '%d/%m/%y')) %>%
  difftime(VisitDate[1:(length(VisitDate)-1)] , VisitDate[2:length(VisitDate)])
```

but I get the error

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1, tz = tz) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time1' to class “POSIXct”
```

Comment: What is the expected output Format?

Comment: Your column name is 'Date' and you are using `VisitDate'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Explanation:**

(i) The format provided in as.Date should be changed to `%Y-%m-%d`. (ii) Your variable should be changed to as.Date if you want it to be recognized as such. In your code, it is only used to arrange the database but is not recognized later. (iii) Using lag makes is more useful.

**Code:**

I think that the last chunk output is what you want in comparison with the second chunk.

```
# SAMPLE DATA -------------------------------------------------------------  
EndoSubsetOnSurveil <-
  data.frame(Person = c(1,1,2,2), 
             VisitDate = c("2004-06-04", "2016-06-03", "2016-07-01",
                           "2016-08-01"))
EndoSubsetOnSurveil$VisitDate <-
  as.Date(EndoSubsetOnSurveil$VisitDate, '%Y-%m-%d')

# DIFFERENCE BETWEEN VISIT WITHOUT GROUPING -------------------------------  
library(dplyr)
EndoSubsetOnSurveil %>% arrange(Person, VisitDate) %>%
  mutate(diffDate = difftime(VisitDate, lag(VisitDate,1)))

# DIFFERENCE BETWEEN VISIT BY PATIENT -------------------------------------  
EndoSubsetOnSurveil %>% arrange(Person, VisitDate) %>% group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(diffDate = difftime(VisitDate, lag(VisitDate,1))) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: @Sebastian I added `ungroup()` in the last line of the code to return the data in its original format.